# Is there a way for fluentd to read config from Azure Vault?

Tags: mongodb, azure, logging, azure-keyvault, fluentd

I have fluentd instance that I'm using to collect application logs and store them into mongodb using [mongo-plugin](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-mongo) .

It works well but the problem is that I have to put mongo credentials inside fluentd config file and those configs are saved in Azure Vault Service.
I need a way to extract those credentials and inject it to fluentd config file

fluent.conf

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match mongo.**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type mongo
    host [host]
    port [port]
    database [db]
    collection [collection]
    auth_source [auth db]

    # authentication
    user [user]
    password [password]

    <inject>
    # key name of timestamp
      time_key time
    </inject>

    <buffer>
    # flush
    flush_interval 10s
    </buffer>
  </store>

</match>
```

As you see I need to extract the credentials in `[]` from vault and use them inside fluentd config file .

I'm using mongo Atlas

Comment: Can you not use the environment variables instead of hardcoding credentials in the config file?

Comment: for security reason , I don't want to set ENV

Comment: Right. What about fetching creds from Azure Vault and then replacing those in the configuration file before starting `fluentd`?

Comment: That's possible but the problem is that this container will be inside the customer cloud and since he can have access to ENV , I want to use fluentd plugins to call an api so that api will return result to fluentd after that fluentd will save these secrets s variable and use them to connect to mongo

Comment: Please take a look at https://github.com/HatsuneMiku3939/fluent-plugin-http-pull.

Comment: I did It successfully make request , the problem is that I want to use the output of the response save it to variable and use that variable mongo section

Comment: Your requirement is very constrained. Looks like https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-mongo itself should have something like that for authentication as other usual methods are not enough for your use case. You can create an issue on the repo for its inclusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252165/discussion-between-slifer2015-and-azeem).